# Prove that $(x^3-2)$ is a maximal ideal of $\Bbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Prove $(x^3-2)$ is maximal ideal of $\Bbb  Q[x]$ using isomorphism theorems for rings.

I tried using the second isomorphism theorem for rings, to use that $( x ^ 3-2)$ is maximal if and only if $\mathbb Q [x ] / ( x ^ 3-2)$ is field . Seeing that $\mathbb Q [x ] / ( x ^ 3-2)$ is isomorphic to a field related to $\mathbb Q$. I have $A = \mathbb Q [x ]$ , $I = ( x ^ 3-2)$ but not to $B$ take to apply $( B + I) / I  $ isomorphic $B / (B ∩ I )$ field.

Comment: First of all: the title of the question and the text asks of different things. What is your question? Secondly: what have you tried?

Comment: To get better answers, you should add some context to your question - what have you already tried? Do you know some theorems that might help? For example, would it help you to know that $x^3-2$ is irreducible? Can you prove that it is?

Comment: We can prove that $x^3-2$ is irreducible by using Eisenstein test. Notice that the prime number $2$ divides all non-leading coefficients of $x^3-2$ and its square $2^2$ doesn't divide the constant term $2$. As you were told below, $x^3-2$ being irreducible gives you that $(x^3-2)$ is maximal. This, in turn, gives you that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ is a field.

Comment: Now, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ has an element (let me call it $\overline{x}$), which is the class of $x$ or $x+(x^3-2)$, that satisfies $\overline{x}^3-2=0$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$. But there is no element $r$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ that satisfies $r^3-2=0$. Therefore it cannot be that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ defined by $p(x)\mapsto p(\sqrt[3]{2})$. This well defined, homomorphism, and onto. Its Kernel it the set of polynomials that vanish when evaluated at $\sqrt[3]{2}$.
the polynomial $x^3-2$ is one of them. By Einsenstein's test (as above) it is irreductible, therefore any other polynomial  vanishing at $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is divisible by $x^3-2$. Therefore $\text{Ker}(f)=(x^3-2)$.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal $(x^3-2)$ is maximal iff $x^3 - 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is obvious.

Comment: You are using a certain property of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which it would be helpful to future Readers to state explicitly.